# How to interpret the value for the given problem?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Given:

"Hariharan  goes to a shop to buy an FM radio costing $ 1404 including sales tax at 8% He asks the shopkeeper to reduce the price of radio so that he can save the amount equal to the sales tax. The reduction of the price of the radio is:"

Questions:

What exactly is the problem telling us to calculate? What factor are we asked to calculate here?

Comment: Why people keep using doubt in their questions ? It makes no sense

Comment: It is not your fault, who ever posed a problem like this needs to learn basic communication skills , depending on how one reads it it makes different sense , my advice is try to imagine all the possible ways that it might make sense and answer each one , this is not a math problem but simple lack of ability to be clear

Comment: $P$ is the original purchase price, ignoring tax.  $Q$ is the new purchase price, ignoring tax.  You are being asked to compute $P - Q$.  Then $$1.08P = 1404 ~~\text{and}~~ 1.08Q = P.$$

Comment: Re previous comment : "The reduction of the price of the radio is ?" : this is actually ambiguous.  Does price refer to pre-tax or post tax$~$?  That is, are you being asked to compute $P - Q$, re previous comment or $[(1.08P) - (1.08Q)] = 1404 - P ~$?  Personally, I make it a coin-flip, which interpretation the problem composer intended.